# Using wish to teleport without rolling on the mishap table

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, wish

A wizard in my group wants to use [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) to cast [*teleport*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleport) without rolling against the mishap table so it'll just take him and his group straight there. His reasoning is that *wish* states:

> You don’t need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.

He has never been to, seen or knows the location of the place he is trying to *teleport* to. He only knows its name and that it exists.

My stance is that if he wants to use *wish* to cast *teleport*, a roll against the table would have to take place.

I was hoping to ask the more knowledgeable people here to settle our discussion.

Comment: In 3.5e, Teleport Without Error was a 7th level spell. Maybe this helps people in the future, maybe not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Pick your poison.

He could use wish either to duplicate the teleport spell, incurring all its mechanics (including the failure chance).

Or he could use wish to create the more powerful effect of “like teleport but without any mishap chance”, which instead incurs the stresses of pushing a wish spell that hard.

Comment: This is my belief too. I wonder if this is the general consensus.

Comment: @Jinzuku a consensus with your DM is all that matters

Comment: In this instance, I'm the DM. My friend and I can't come to a consensus, which is why I asked here to provide the tie-breaker.

Comment: @Jinzuku It sounds like you’ve already given him this choice, and that he responded with something other than taking one of the options. Is this accurate?

Comment: Kind of. I presented the 2 options above and he responded with a third option which I explained in the original post. We couldn't come to an agreement. I did see his point of view though so I didn't shoot it down. We are both fairly new to D&D as a whole so thought it would be best to seek counsel from the more experienced.

Comment: Your friend is simply wrong. The "rolling on the table" is part of the Teleport spell's *effect*, so even if the spell "simply takes effect," he has to roll on the table.